# How do I pull out a selection And it shows the size of the region

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, user-interface

[image]

To enable the mouse to pull out a selection range, release the mouse after selection and display the values of the `width` and `height` of the `X-axis` and `Y-axis` of the selected area in these four fields.

This is my problem. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Post your js or playground,sandbox etc

Answer (score 0):

I created small codepen for one of  possible solutions, You need to adjust it to Your case.

[Coepen Select Area](https://codepen.io/granis/pen/eXqXvd)

```
let isDragging = false;
const startArr=[];
document.getElementById('target_element').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
  startArr[0] = e.offsetX;
  startArr[1] = e.offsetY;
  isDragging=true
})

const currentArr=[]
document.getElementById('target_element').addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  if (isDragging){
    currentArr[0] = e.offsetX;
    currentArr[1] = e.offsetY;

    const dimensions = getDimensions(startArr, currentArr);
    const parentElement = document.getElementById('target_element');
    parentElement.innerHTML = '';
    const selectWindow = document.createElement('div');
    selectWindow.style.position = 'absolute';
    selectWindow.style.height = dimensions.h+'px';
    selectWindow.style.width = dimensions.w+'px';
    selectWindow.style.top = dimensions.y+'px';
    selectWindow.style.left = dimensions.x+'px';
    selectWindow.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    parentElement.appendChild(selectWindow);
    currentArr.length = 0;
  }
})
const finishArr=[];
document.getElementById('target_element').addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
  if (isDragging){
    finishArr[0] = e.offsetX;
    finishArr[1] = e.offsetY;

    const dimensions = getDimensions(startArr, finishArr);
    document.getElementById('x').innerText = dimensions.x;
    document.getElementById('y').innerText = dimensions.y;
    document.getElementById('w').innerText = dimensions.w;
    document.getElementById('h').innerText = dimensions.h;
    isDragging=false;
  }
})
function getDimensions(startingPoint, finishPoint){
  const top = Math.min(startingPoint[1], finishPoint[1]);
  const bottom = Math.max(startingPoint[1], finishPoint[1]);
  const left = Math.min(startingPoint[0], finishPoint[0]);
  const right = Math.max(startingPoint[0], finishPoint[0]);
  return {
    x: left,
    y: top,
    w: right-left,
    h: bottom-top
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your method, it really helped me a lot!


This is what I want to achieve!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply!

If you want the object to drag and move, how do you write it?



Ps. Think for many days do not know how to implement!